# Writing libraries with typescript and generics

Tags: javascript, typescript, generics

So I'm writing a library with typescript and obviously, most people who will use it will be using javascript. My question is if I want to have a generic function in my library for example: 

`testFunction<TestType>("hello world")`

If transpiled that into javascript, how would people using javascript interact with that generic function? Will I have to not use generics for the sake of the javascript user's? or does typescript have a way of making it work for javascript users?

Comment: Have you checked how it compiles to JS? Why not?

Comment: @zerkms Yes, i have. that is why I was asking. I figured maybe I wasn't passing the correct flag or I was missing something... plus the transpiled javascript can in a lot of cases look like complete jibberish.

Comment: "Yes, i have. that is why I was asking" --- because from your answer it looks like you haven't, sorry

Comment: @zerkms "I figured maybe I wasn't passing the correct flag or I was missing something..."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once your TypeScript is transpiled to JavaScript, downstream clients will lose the type information. In other words, JavaScript clients will just see the equivalent of `testFunction("helloWorld");`. For downstream clients that are using TypeScript, they will be able to gain benefits (static analysis, type checks, auto-completion) from using your types as defined in your package.json.